# Why am I getting a Chrome error when applying <meta> for responsiveness?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am watching this video and I see they wanted me to use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=display-width, initial-scale=1">
```

for more of a responsive website, keep in mind I am in the early stages of learning, even if there is a better way I am trying to learn step by step, but then in chrome when I check my code out and responsiveness I get,

> The value "display-width" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.

Do I need to end the meta with `</meta>` at the end of it at the bottom as well or do I ignore the error?

Comment: The error is being reported correctly. Read about meta at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag You should be using device-width. As a general tip, use reliable sources such as MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/, to look up syntax, spelling, meaning before posting here as it shows people you have done some research. Let me know if the reference doesn't clarify when you need to use meta.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note this is a programming site where you can absolutely post source code, you only need to click the `{}` (Code Sample) toolbar button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `<meta>` viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Ohh, it was a device instead of a display, thank you so much i really appreciate it!